# Chrome: How to set a dynamically created <input date> date picker based on a string "dd/mm/yyyy"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, dynamic, input

Some `<td>` tag contains a string date `dd/mm/yyyy` like 24/5/2012
I need to read this string date and use it to dynamically set the value of a dynamically created input date tag.

```
var stringDate = selectedEl.text();
anotherEl.html("<input type='date' value='" + stringDate + "'/>");
```

The code above has no effect. The Chrome browser just renders its empty default date picker field that contains: `dd ----- yyy`

Comment: It's not empty then is it, if it contains `dd ----- yyy`. What is the value of `stringDate`?

Comment: @JayMee `dd ----- yyy` is the default for Chrome empty date input field

Comment: What's the value of `stringDate`?

Comment: It take the format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9519493/1370442

Comment: @JayMee `stringDate` has the text `24/5/2012`

Comment: @ShaunakD The formate of the `<input type="date" />` is baed on the user's local calendar format.

Answer (score 0):

Input type date takes the format yyyy-mm-dd but displays the date localised to the browser (Chrome). So you should be able to supply the date in the format yyyy-mm-dd and it display correctly depending on localisation settings. Checkout this [codepen](http://codepen.io/bUKaneer/pen/qdPmQe)

```
<input type="date" value="2008-09-05" />
```